# XCUITest unexpected behaviour

Tags: ios, swift, xctest

I have a simply project with a tableView and a detail vc. The tableView displays 20 rows with "cell (n)" text and the detail view shows a label with the cell pressed.
I want to assert given a tap into a cell i get the text found in the tableView in the detail vc label. So for instance if i tap of the cell 3, which contains "cell 3" i want to get this text, instead of hardcoding it, and assert that i can find this text in the detail vc.

```
func testCanNavigateToDetailVCWithTheTextFromCell() {
    let labelInTableView = app.staticTexts["cell 3"]

    labelInTableView.tap()

    let labelInDetailVC = app.staticTexts[labelInTableView.label]
    XCTAssertTrue(labelInDetailVC.exists)
}
```

This seems working. But i want to do this:

```
func testCanNavigateToDetailVCWithTheTextFromCellV2() {
    let cell = app.tables.element.cells.element(boundBy: 3)  //Get the third cell of the unique tableView

    cell.tap()

    let textFromPreviousCell = cell.staticTexts.element(boundBy: 0).label  //Since is a "Basic" cell it only has one label.
    //I will also want to set an accessilibtyIdentifier to the label and access it via cell.staticTexts["id"].label
    let labelInDetailVC = app.staticTexts[textFromPreviousCell]
    XCTAssertTrue(labelInDetailVC.exists)
}
```

I set up a project with this issue [here](http://ruiznadal.com/TestUI_god.zip)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to get the text of the cell after tapping it. This means that the cell is no longer on the screen (the new screen has appeared). All you need to do is change the order of the lines `cell.tap()` and `let textFromPreviousCell = cell.staticTexts.element(boundBy: 0).label`. See the new function below:

```
func testCanNavigateToDetailVCWithTheTextFromCellV2() {
    let cell = app.tables.element.cells.element(boundBy: 3)  //Get the third cell of the unique tableView

    let textFromPreviousCell = cell.staticTexts.element(boundBy: 0).label  //Since is a "Basic" cell it only has one label.

    cell.tap()

    let labelInDetailVC = app.staticTexts[textFromPreviousCell]
    XCTAssertTrue(labelInDetailVC.exists)
}
```